# PowerShell: Determine true/false on CloseMainWindow() without actually closing window

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a series of running processes I need to stop as gracefully as I can. I am finding that I can use CloseMainWindow() with any foreground process, but that none of the ones running in the system tray (i.e. background processes) end (just returning 'false'). That on it's own isn't an issue since I can force-quite those (e.g. Stop-Process) if needed.

However, how can I determine true/false of CloseMainWindow() on each process without actually closing the ones that return true? I could not find anything property that gave the foreground/background status of a process.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out how to do this, though I am not certain it's the most reliable way.

I found that querying the MainWindowHandle property against a process return 0 only if it was running without a window in the background. Otherwise it would return some value > 0. If there's a better way, feel free to educate me.